# Creating a new table in mongoose based on object IDs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hello the title of this question is very poorly worded however i will better explain the issue.

I have a document called 'buildings', and I also have two documents called 'rooms' and 'logins'. In both rooms and logins, they have an embedded document of building as follows:

Room Schema:

```
const roomSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 1,
    maxlength: 255
  },
  building: {
    type: new mongoose.Schema({
      name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: 1,
        maxlength: 255
      }
    }),
    required: true
  }
});
```

Logins Schema:

```
const loginSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  user: {
    type: new mongoose.Schema({
      email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      isVisitor: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: true
      }
    })
  },
  dateIn: {
    type: Date,
    required: true,
    default: Date.now()
  },
  dateOut: {
    type: Date
  },
  building: {
    type: new mongoose.Schema({
      name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      }
    })
  }
});
```

And the building schema is as follows:

```
const Building = mongoose.model(
  "Building",
  new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      minlength: 1,
      maxlength: 255
    },
    address: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      minlength: 1,
      maxlength: 255
    },
    postcode: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      minlength: 6,
      maxlength: 8
    },
    organisation: {
      type: new mongoose.Schema({
        name: {
          type: String,
          required: true
        }
      })
    }
  })
);
```

Here is some examples of documents from each schema:

Building:

```
{
    "_id": "5c79a31ed2016312ecd27c46",
    "name": "TusPark",
    "site": {
        "_id": "5c79a243d2016312ecd27c45",
        "name": "TusPark Newcastle"
    },
    "__v": 0
},
```

Rooms:

```
{
    "_id": "5c7fa01abdd6233d6fdbc917",
    "name": "E101",
    "building": {
        "_id": "5c79a31ed2016312ecd27c46",
        "name": "TusPark"
    },
    "__v": 0
},
```

Logins:

```
{
    "dateIn": "2019-03-21T13:13:23.069Z",
    "_id": "5c938e151bd7a02d479893bd",
    "user": {
        "_id": "5c925378e88bb72764283108",
        "email": "jack1@gmail.com",
        "isVisitor": true
    },
    "building": {
        "_id": "5c79a31ed2016312ecd27c46",
        "name": "TusPark"
    },
    "__v": 0
}
```

I am trying to send a document to the client which contains the building details, with the rooms and logins embedded as attributes for the relevant building. The code I currently have written for this is below:

```
router.get("/all", async (req, res) => {
  const buildings = await Building.find();

  const rooms = await Room.find({
    building_id: buildings._id
  });

  const logins = await Login.find({
    building_id: buildings._id
  });

  const building_rooms = await Building.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "rooms",
        localField: "building_id",
        foreignField: "building_id",
        as: "building_rooms"
      }
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "logins",
        localField: "building_id",
        foreignField: "building_id",
        as: "building_logins"
      }
    }
  ]);

  res.send(building_rooms);
});
```

Note I have purposely not included $unwind

The current output for this request is:

```
[
{
    "_id": "5c79a31ed2016312ecd27c46",
    "name": "Park",
    "site": {
        "_id": "5c79a243d2016312ecd27c45",
        "name": "Park Newcastle"
    },
    "__v": 0,
    "building_rooms": [
        {
            "_id": "5c7fa01abdd6233d6fdbc917",
            "name": "E101",
            "building": {
                "_id": "5c79a31ed2016312ecd27c46",
                "name": "Park"
            },
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "5c7fdbd12229db40589e41b5",
            "name": "E202",
            "building": {
                "_id": "5c79a31ed2016312ecd27c46",
                "name": "Park"
            },
            "__v": 0
        }
    ],
    "building_logins": [
        {
            "_id": "5c91483402d1a4145a2c4d9b",
            "dateIn": "2019-03-19T19:51:06.458Z",
            "user": {
                "_id": "5c83b4b87321805bad025e65",
                "email": "bob1999@gmail.com",
                "isVisitor": true
            },
            "building": {
                "_id": "5c79a31ed2016312ecd27c46",
                "name": "Park"
            },
            "__v": 0,
            "dateOut": "2019-03-20T11:55:19.205Z"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id": "5c925475e88bb72764283113",
    "name": "Manchester",
    "site": {
        "_id": "5c921c94a922f6236cbe37d2",
        "name": "Manchester"
    },
    "__v": 0,
    "building_rooms": [
        {
            "_id": "5c7fa01abdd6233d6fdbc917",
            "name": "E101",
            "building": {
                "_id": "5c79a31ed2016312ecd27c46",
                "name": "Park"
            },
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "5c7fdbd12229db40589e41b5",
            "name": "E202",
            "building": {
                "_id": "5c79a31ed2016312ecd27c46",
                "name": "Park"
            },
            "__v": 0
        }
    ],
    "building_logins": [
        {
            "_id": "5c91483402d1a4145a2c4d9b",
            "dateIn": "2019-03-19T19:51:06.458Z",
            "user": {
                "_id": "5c83b4b87321805bad025e65",
                "email": "bob1999@gmail.com",
                "isVisitor": true
            },
            "building": {
                "_id": "5c79a31ed2016312ecd27c46",
                "name": "Park"
            },
            "__v": 0,
            "dateOut": "2019-03-20T11:55:19.205Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

]

However the issue is that the logins and rooms of 'Park' are being embedded in manchester building. which is not correct.

The correct output should be:

```
    [
{
    "_id": "5c79a31ed2016312ecd27c46",
    "name": "Park",
    "site": {
        "_id": "5c79a243d2016312ecd27c45",
        "name": "Park Newcastle"
    },
    "__v": 0,
    "building_rooms": [
        {
            "_id": "5c7fa01abdd6233d6fdbc917",
            "name": "E101",
            "building": {
                "_id": "5c79a31ed2016312ecd27c46",
                "name": "Park"
            },
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "5c7fdbd12229db40589e41b5",
            "name": "E202",
            "building": {
                "_id": "5c79a31ed2016312ecd27c46",
                "name": "Park"
            },
            "__v": 0
        }
    ],
    "building_logins": [
        {
            "_id": "5c91483402d1a4145a2c4d9b",
            "dateIn": "2019-03-19T19:51:06.458Z",
            "user": {
                "_id": "5c83b4b87321805bad025e65",
                "email": "bob1999@gmail.com",
                "isVisitor": true
            },
            "building": {
                "_id": "5c79a31ed2016312ecd27c46",
                "name": "Park"
            },
            "__v": 0,
            "dateOut": "2019-03-20T11:55:19.205Z"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id": "5c925475e88bb72764283113",
    "name": "Manchester",
    "site": {
        "_id": "5c921c94a922f6236cbe37d2",
        "name": "Manchester"
    },
    "__v": 0,
    "building_rooms": [],
    "building_logins": []
}
```

]

With there being no instances of building_rooms or building_logs as there are no logins or rooms with the object ID relating to manchester.

I really appreciate the time taken to read this and would be grateful for any help with solving tis problem.

Comment: What you claim as output does not match the query provided. You only included schema for **one** of the collections when you want to join **three**. Noting also that your "correct output" does not contain the fields `building_id` that you refer to in your `$lookup` statements. I only see `'site._id'` in the master document, and `building._id` within other output paths. You would be better off showing a small sample of documents from each collection from which it is possible to obtain your expected result. Then  we can tell you what you are doing wrong. Please edit to include details.

Comment: Hi thanks for the feedback, ive added in the other schemas and an example document of each. In the 'correct output' I just made the "building_rooms" and "building_logins" empty for manchester as there are no rooms or logins that match the building ID for manchester.